# Change element color on click and back when clicking off

Tags: javascript, input

I'm trying to make font awesome icons I'm using change colour on click of an input with javascript, and change back to normal when it is clicked off.

The problem I have is that it only works for one input, I need it to work for 4 different inputs. Thanks.

```js
const User = document.getElementById("User-icon");
const Name = document.getElementById("Name");

Name.addEventListener("click", function(Name) {
  User.style.color = "#0773b5";
  Name.preventDefault();
  Name.stopPropagation();
});
window.onclick = function(Name) {
  User.style.color = "rgba(211,211,211,1)";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
<div class="Wrapper">
  <h1>Contact Us</h1>
  <div class="Contact-form">
    <form id="reset">
      <div class="form-group" id="Name-group">
        <i class="fas fa-user" id="User-icon"></i>
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="Name" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Name" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group" id="Phone-group">
        <i class="fas fa-phone" id="Phone-icon"></i>
        <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control" id="Phone" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Phone" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group" id="Email-group">
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="Email" autocomplete="on" required onkeydown="validation()">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group" id="Message-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" id="Message" rows="5" cols="5" name="message" required></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group" id="Submit-button">
        <input type="submit" name="" id="btn" class="form-control btn btn-default" value="Send">
      </div>
      <div id="msg"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear to me, do you want to change the color of the icon when the user focuses on its input and get the color back when it's blured?

Comment: no `</form>` your code is invalid....

Answer (score 1):

You missed a closing form tag `</form>`, here is a solution for your problem using event delegation, no need for those ids ;)

```js
document.querySelector(".Contact-form form").addEventListener("focus", function(e) {
  // check if the previous element of the clicked element is an `i` element
  // then add the class active to it
  if(e.target.previousElementSibling?.nodeName === "I") {
    e.target.previousElementSibling.classList.add("active");
  }
}, true);

document.querySelector(".Contact-form form").addEventListener("blur", function() {
  // check if there is an active `i` element than remove that class
  this.querySelector("i.active")?.classList.remove("active");
}, true);

function validation() {
  // your validation code
}
```

```css
i.active {
  color: #0773b5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
<div class="Wrapper">
  <h1>Contact Us</h1>
  <div class="Contact-form">
    <form id="reset">
      <div class="form-group" id="Name-group">
        <i class="fas fa-user" id="User-icon"></i>
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="Name" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Name" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group" id="Phone-group">
        <i class="fas fa-phone" id="Phone-icon"></i>
        <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control" id="Phone" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Phone" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group" id="Email-group">
        <i class="fas fa-at" id="Phone-icon"></i>
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="Email" autocomplete="on" required onkeydown="validation()">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group" id="Message-group">
        <i class="fas fa-envelope" id="Phone-icon"></i>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="Message" rows="5" cols="5" name="message" required></textarea>
        </div>
      <div class="form-group" id="Submit-button">
        <input type="submit" name="" id="btn" class="form-control btn btn-default" value="Send">
      </div>
    </form>
    <div id="msg"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, however when I put it in the name and phone icons don't work, the email and message icons work fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you should not use the click event.
For example the tabulation key is used to switch from one input to another.
You must use the focus and blur events

```js
const myForm = document.getElementById('my-form')
  ;
myForm.querySelectorAll('input, textarea').forEach(el=>
  {
  el.onfocus = e => setIconFocus( e, true )
  el.onblur = e => setIconFocus( e, false )
  })
function setIconFocus(e, onOff )
  {
  let ikon = e.target.closest('#my-form div').querySelector('i.fas')
  if (ikon) ikon.classList.toggle('focusColor', onOff)
  }
myForm.onsubmit = e =>
  {
  console.clear()
  e.preventDefault() // disable submit for testing here
  }
myForm.Email.onkeydown = e =>
  {
  console.clear()
  console.log('input Email = ', myForm.Email.value )
  // your code of validation() 
  }
```

```css
body, textarea, input  {
  font-family : Helvetica, Arial sans-serif;
  font-size   : 16px;
  }
#my-form div {
  position : relative; 
  padding  : .2em 0 0 1em;
  }
#my-form div i.fas {
  position : absolute; 
  top      : 1em;
  left     : .6em;
  }
#my-form div i.fas.focusColor {
  color : #0773b5;
  }
#my-form div input,
#my-form div textarea {
  display    : inline-block;
  box-sizing : border-box; 
  width      : 14em; 
  margin     : .5em 0 .7em 1.3em;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" />

<form id="my-form">
  <div>
    <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
    <input name="Name"  type="text" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Name" required>
  </div>
  <div>
    <i class="fas fa-phone"></i>
    <input name="Phone" type="text" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Phone" required>
  </div>
  <div>
    <i class="fas fa-at" ></i>
    <input name="Email" type="email" autocomplete="on" required >
  </div>
  <div>
    <i class="fas fa-envelope-open-text" ></i>
    <textarea name="Message"   required></textarea>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="submit" >Send</button> 
  </div>
</form>
```